# What happens with the cache when not enough addresses are put into it in set associative cache?

Tags: caching

I am working on an assignment with set-associative Cache and come with an question. I am working with 16 bytes of set-associative cache, where the block is 2 bytes set in cache of four blocks.

per my understanding, a cache set up such as this would have four blocks of cache that can hold two sets each (one half for a set of 0 and one half for a set of 1). If only 4 addresses have been loaded (and we assume some addresses overlap with the same block sometimes), then it would leave to reason that system would have those caches be empty.

To simplify, in a set-associative cache system, is it possible for some cache to be empty (in theory), or does the system auto fill with the memory.